# Indentation rules in classes with inheritance?

Tags: f#

I am a bit confused by the F# compiler (via Ionide) regarding indentation rules.

Here is my code snippet that triggers warnings:

```
type MyGame () as this =
  inherit Game ()
    let graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager (this)
    let mutable spriteBatch = null
    let mutable state =
      {
        Board = Map.empty
        Selection = List.empty
      }

    do
      this.IsMouseVisible <- true

    // ...
```

But F# only seems happy when I indent each line one or more characters from the previous, which looks... odd to me:

```
type MyGame () as this =
  inherit Game ()
    let graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager (this)
      let mutable spriteBatch = null
        let mutable state =
          {
            Board = Map.empty
            Selection = List.empty
          }

          do
            this.IsMouseVisible <- true

    // ...
```

How *should* code like this be formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `inherit Game ()` line is not as indented as what comes next. Change the indentation, and the warnings go away:

```
type MyGame () as this =
    inherit Game ()
    let graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager (this)
    let mutable spriteBatch = null
    let mutable state =
      {
        Board = Map.empty
        Selection = List.empty
      }

    do
      this.IsMouseVisible <- true

    // ...
```

Also note that sometimes that *your* indentation will be superior to what the compiler suggests.